# SQL Table Max Rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an application which will require storage of 4-5 trillion records.  I'm unfamiliar with limitations of mySQL, is it capable of data volumes this large?  Is there going to be an issue with performance?

Would I be better off breaking it into multiple tables?

Comment: At 50 bytes per row (a number of bytes I obtained using an algorithm referred to in the literature as "aerial extraction"), that's 250 Terabytes. The question goes beyond just whether MySQL is "capable" of storing that volume. What is the plan for backing that data up? Any replication? Any disaster recovery site? What is the rate of insert/update/delete and the how much of the data is going to have to be examined to satisfy the queries that are being planned. This question (with more details) might better be asked on **dba.stackexchange.com**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limitation on your table will be the amount of memory it takes rather than the number of records per se.

On a Win32 system running NTFS, the maximum table size in MySQL is around 2TB.  Assuming you have a rudimentary table with a single field of width 4 bytes, this would mean the maximum number of records a table could have is:

```
2000000000000 bytes / 4 bytes per field = 500000000000 = 5 billion records
```

So it would seem that you would not be able to use MySQL for your purposes.  You can try looking into a NoSQL solution like Cassandra.

You can also read [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890296/what-is-maximum-records-quantity-a-mysql-table-can-store) for more information.